# Which is a better approach when updating records using batch class, to place it in execute or finish method?

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, dml, asynchronous

Sorry but I am new to this and I just wander, do you think it is better to put all the millions of records inside the Map object which is process by the execute method, however the dml where the update will happen will be on the finish method?

Any scenarios where it is best to place the dml in execute or finish method?

Answer (score 0):

In Salesforce batch Apex, the best practice is to perform **DML** operations in the **execute** method, not in the **finish** method. This is because the **finish** method is intended for **post-processing** operations, such as sending confirmation emails or logging errors, not for updating records. The finish method is also executed only once after all the batches are processed, so it is not suitable for handling bulk records.

There are some scenarios where it is better to place the DML in the execute method, such as:

- When you want to update the records in batches, rather than in one large transaction, to avoid hitting governor limits or locking issues. For example, if you have a batch Apex job that updates millions of records, you can use the scope parameter of the `Database.executeBatch` method to specify the batch size, and then perform the DML in the execute method for each batch. This way, you can process the records in smaller chunks and avoid hitting the limits for the number of records processed in a single transaction or the number of rows locked in a table.
- When you want to handle errors or exceptions for each batch, rather
  than for the entire job, to avoid losing data or causing
  inconsistencies. For example, if you have a batch Apex job that
  updates records based on some criteria, you can use the Database
  class methods, such as `Database.update`, to perform the DML in the
  execute method and get the result for each record. This way, you can
  check the result for each record and handle any errors or exceptions
  that occur, such as validation errors or trigger errors. You can also
  use the `Database.Stateful` interface to maintain the state across
  batches and store the error information for later processing.

[Batch Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm)

[Batch Apex in Salesforce: Benefits, Use Cases, and Best Practices](https://www.saasguru.co/batch-apex-salesforce/)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the info! Greatly appreciate it!